# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console, android-build, android-app-signing

My development and build environment for this Android app is `Expo (React Native)`, and App signing is managed by Google Play.

I have already built and uploaded app bundles, this time I'm receiving error: `Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again:SHA1: <SHA KEY>`

I read couple of answers, but they are either a bit confusing, or not explained keeping in mind Expo.

I have verified that the slug name, and the app name is unchanged.

I have the `.keystore` file with me (it if makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Upload certificate from expo servers, and shared the same with Google Support, and requested them to update with this new certificate which I downloaded.

Comment: Can you please share how you fetched the certificate?